# Skipping warnings

Tags: grep, find

I thought this would skip warnings containing "Permission":

```
$ find / -iname "*mysql*" | grep -v "Permission"
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
```

But it doesn't. Any suggestion?

In comparison, this works as expected:

```
$mkdir foo
$ls | grep -v "foo"
```

Comment: I think it has to do with redirecting to stdout from stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings are not being redirected.  This would help:

```
find / -iname "*mysql*" 2>/dev/null | grep -v "Permission"
```

although you might *want* to see warnings other than "Permission":

```
find / -iname "*mysql*" 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission"
```

Answer (score 1):

The warnings of `find` are being shown on the error stream, STDERR, file descriptor 2, but with the pipe you are redirecting just the STDOUT (file descriptor 1), and using `grep` on that, as a result the messages are still being shown.

**Solutions:**

As you are not interested in the warnings, simply redirect STDERR to `/dev/null`:

```
find / -iname "*mysql*" 2>/dev/null
```

If you must use `grep`, pass both STDOUT and STDERR, and then use your `grep -v "Permission"` command:

If your shell supports `|&`:

```
find / -iname "*mysql*" |& grep -v "Permission"
```

POSIX-ly:

```
find / -iname "*mysql*" 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission"
```

---

As a side note, look the source of the warnings. Presumably there are permission issues as you are probably running as non-root user, to fix this issue run the `find` command as `root` or limit your searching surface accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` utility, like most other utilities, write error messages to the *standard error stream*.

Your pipe will redirect the *standard output stream* of `find` to `grep`, but the error stream will still go to the console.

To redirect the error stream of `find`, use `2>&1` if you want to process it with `grep` (this means "send errors wherever ordinary output goes"):

```
find / -iname "*mysql*" 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission"
```

However, since you *probably* want errors to go away, use

```
find / -iname "*mysql*" 2>/dev/null
```

This will make the error stream of `find` go into the bit bucket `/dev/null` (a device file that never can be filled).